# Where is APK file after "phonegap build android" command?

Tags: android, cordova, ant

After "phonegap build android" command,i searched .apk file on `D:\firstapp\platforms\android\ant-build` but i found only the `CordovaApp-debug.apk` and `CordovaApp-debug-unaligned.apk` file...

where can i get my .apk file, Also my app name if `firstapp`, still only `CordovaApp-debug.apk` file found..

Actually i'm new to phonegap, help me...

Answer (score 6):

You found the right apk. Cordova is the new name for Phone Gap. `CordovaApp-debug.apk` is your apk. The `-debug` part means that it was signed with the default debug key.

You need to sign it with your own key when you upload the apk to Google Play. But for now, you can use the current apk you have to test it on your own device, or on your friends devices.

Answer (score 2):

Cordova has changed name fixed to CordovaApp to avoid issues with unicode app name (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6511)

If your application name is normal (A..z) you can revert this behaviour by changine line 217 of C:\Users\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\lib

from:

```
var safe_activity_name = "CordovaApp"
```

to:

```
var safe_activity_name = project_name.replace(/\W/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

CordovaApp-debug.apk is your .apk, cordova will not generate apk with your application name. It will be "CordovaApp-debug.apk"